# Boot mode issue in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, boot

Ive a little problem with Server 2008 R2. Recently I've stuck in safe boot loop. After few tricks I was able to login to server, but right now I can't select Normal Boot mode. When I'm selecting this mode, `msconfig` window  automatically switch to Safe mode in Boot Tab. I can't get ovet it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, when you uncheck the safe boot option, it boots into safe mode anyway and re-checks the option? Sounds like you have more issues than you think. Try deselecting it and checking the box to make it permanent (the one under the timeout box).

Comment: Ive tried many combos, didny work. Sounds like you have more issues than you think - any suggesions?

Comment: It's going into safe mode for a reason...review event logs and possibly do a repair reinstall of Windows to fix.